# write zeros command

Tags: 14.04

I have a question about the command used to write zeros

it is normally: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null`

but in some websites I found this : `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1M`

or  `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=8M`

Could you explain the effects of `bs=1M` and `bs=8M`?

Comment: A note here too - to make it clear: `sudo dd ... of=/dev/sda` will **WIPE OUT** the data on your 'first' harddisk - Use it only when you're VERY SURE you are doing THE RIGHT THING.

Answer (score 3):

#### don't do that especially with a `sudo` unless you REALLY know what you are doing, it will destroy your disks easily.

You probably mean `bs`, block size:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % dd if=/dev/zero of=test.dat sb=10
dd: unrecognised operand ‘sb=10’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.
```

`bs` means that `dd` writes and reads in blocks the size you specify. `1M` means 1 Mbyte.

```
⌂66% [romano:~/tmp] 1 % dd if=/dev/zero of=test.dat bs=10
^C959453+0 records in
959452+0 records out
9594520 bytes (9.6 MB) copied, 1.06318 s, 9.0 MB/s
```

`sb` does not exists. You can find all of this (and more) in `man dd`.

Comment: Now we wait for the 1st person to ignore your warning.

Comment: I was  tempted to edit out the `sudo`s in the question, or at least find a way to make them not copy&pasteable. But well, you know, the rope...

Answer (score 2):

dd can be quite dangerous, one good acronym for it's name is "Data Destroyer", it can overwrite any drive with the slightest typo.

`man dd` or `info coreutils 'dd invocation'` should tell you all you ever (never?) wanted to know about using `dd`, and man should work for just about any terminal program too.

There is no dd option `sb=`, though there is a `bs=`

```
   bs=BYTES
          read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
 Set both input and output block sizes to BYTES.  This makes `dd'
 read and write BYTES per block, overriding any `ibs' and `obs'
 settings.  In addition, if no data-transforming `conv' option is
 specified, input is copied to the output as soon as it's read,
 even if it is smaller than the block size.

...

   N and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes: c
   =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024, xM =M
   GB =1000*1000*1000, G =1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

The numeric-valued strings above (N and BYTES) can be followed by a
multiplier: `b'=512, `c'=1, `w'=2, `xM'=M, or any of the standard block
size suffixes like `k'=1024 (*note Block size::).
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `bs`, not `sb`…

For the future: if you want to know what a command does, from the terminal type:

```
man NameOfCommand
```

In this case you would have found:

```
DD(1)                            User Commands                           DD(1)
NAME
       dd - convert and copy a file

SYNOPSIS
       dd [OPERAND]...
       dd OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Copy a file, converting and formatting according to the operands.

       bs=BYTES
              read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
```

So these commands write in blocks of 1MByte and 8MByte instead of the standard sector size (512bytes most of the time, but now always)